# Is there any multi-language floating keyboard software for Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard, language-support

I do not like the way in which the default on-screen keyboard in Ubuntu pops up. I really appreciate the floating keyboard as can be found in Windows. I have found a similar software for Ubuntu called **OnBoard**, but the problem is that it does not have support for multiple languages (only English). Currently, I use IBus for languages other than English (namely Bengali and Hindi), but typing in another language with an English keyboard is very frustrating.

So, is there any software which can provide simple GUI buttons for typing in languages other than English? I don't know if **OnBoard** can do this, so any suggestion regarding that will also work.

Comment: Input methods usually are designed to be used together with an English or other latin keyboard layout. Avro Phonetic certainly is.

It's not quite clear to me what you are after. Possibly an IBus extension named [Typing Booster](https://mike-fabian.github.io/ibus-typing-booster/) might be of interest to you.

Comment: I am after an on-screen floating keyboard which can stay on top of other applications and can be typed using the mouse (or touchscreen).